# How can I get probabilities using predictions of a trained classifier on a Spark stream in Databricks?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have trained a classifier using AutoML in Databricks.
When I do inference on a data stream with Spark, it currently returns the predicted class (0 or 1) but I would like to get the probabilities instead. In sklearn, this would be achieved with predict_proba.

The code in Databricks I am using:

```
import mlflow
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, col
logged_model = 'runs:/<path_to_model>/model'

loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.spark_udf(spark, model_uri=logged_model, result_type='double')

# Predict on a Spark DataFrame.
df_pred = df.withColumn('predictions', loaded_model(struct(*map(col, df.columns))))

(df_pred.writeStream
   .format("delta")
   .outputMode("append")
   .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/delta/events/_checkpoints/")
   .toTable("df_predictions")
)
```

Thanks you for any help.

Comment: Does the Classifier Class provides a getProbablity method or something simiarl? Have you checked the docs for the classifier?